# command line to get the memory used by process

Tags: unix, command-line

What command line should I write to display the memory used by process as well as the process command line and it's pid ?

Something like:

> ```
> pid mem cmdline
> --- --- -------
> 112 12M mysql -param1 5 -param2 12
> 115 15M apache -param1 44 -param2 8
> ...
> ```

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
ps -eo pid,rss,cmd
```

Comment: Thank you. Did not knew it could be so simple

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't there something like the /proc directory?  /proc/[id]/mem should lead you there.